# Grails Mail plugin exception handling

Tags: java, grails, groovy, exception, try-catch

I am using grails 2.4.4 version. I want to know what are the possible exceptions that can be handled with the mail plugin version 1.0.7 and how it can be handled.
Is it possible to handle any of the exceptions in a try-catch-retry block?

Comment: If you catch Exception yes. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: not a specific problem as such. My application is supposed to send mails and i just want to handle any possible exceptions related to that. I could gather a few exceptions such as AddressException, ConnectException and MessageException @Raphael

Answer (score 0):

The main plugin itself throws `IllegalArgumentException`  and `GrailsMailException` but the underlying libraries the plugin uses might throw other exceptions such as IO related.

https://github.com/gpc/grails-mail/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=throw&type=